# How to switch between Scenes in Multi-scene view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multi-scene

I'm testing out this new feature of Unity, allowing to have multiple scenes opened at once. I wonder how to load or unload a certain scene without having the main one (which is basicly UI) closed. I couldn't find any tutorials

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the SceneManager and the additive loading capability. Additive loading means that previous scenes will not be cleared out when the new scene loads.

```
       SceneManager.LoadScene("YourScene", LoadSceneMode.Additive); //Additive
       SceneManager.LoadScene("YourScene", LoadSceneMode.Single); //Conventional loading
```

Just remember that the lighting settings from the active scene will be used for all scenes. This is typically the first scene loaded unless you manually set it like below.

```
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene(SceneManager.GetSceneByName("Scene2"));
```

Some more details can be found at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.LoadSceneMode.Additive.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html